# Why do gate agents wait to ask for volunteers minutes before departure?

Tags: airline-operations

E.g., taking the last flight out of the day. It checks in full, and the airline knows this several hours in advance.  Getting bumped would mean spending the night here again. Would be nice to avoid the commute to and from the airport, and the double dose of TSA. Why doesn't the airline text the pax and ask for volunteers via an online auction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Travel.SE.  The passenger travel aspects of aviation are specifically off-topic here.

Comment: Flights are oversold (on many airlines, tho not all) because it generally works - somebody doesn't show up (takes a different flight, oversleeps, trip cancels, etc) and what was 163 seats sold for a 160 seat airplane, is now 160 or 159 people wanting to travel. But sometimes, everybody shows up, and they have to ask for volunteers. But it's not until everybody HAS showed up, that you know how much you're really over. Nobody PLANS to oversleep or have a late change of plans, but it happens. It's only when you know that you really DO have the 163 people present, that you ask for 3 volunteers.

Comment: @RalphJ, actually, if you sell 163 seats, you can reasonably expect 148 passengers to show up.